# Imprimir todos os 0

Tags: java

Eu declarei a seguinte variável:

```
int sequencia = 000000000;
```

Na hora de imprimir, está imprimindo apenas um 0.

Alguém sabe como faço pra imprimir todos os 0 (zeros) ?

Como faço um auto-incremento a ponto que a cada volta (for) o valor altere para: 000000001,000000002 até chegar 999999999 ?

Comment: Vai ter que imprimir como string, usando printf.

Comment: Você precisa declarar a variável como _string_, o _int_ já converte `00000000` para `0`.

Comment: Esse número será incrementado posteriormente, vou ver como fica tentando usar o parse.

Comment: Matematicamente, 000001 é 1. Se você quer fazer impressão de uma quantidade conhecida de caracteres, você precisará fazer o "zero-padding" até encher o lado esquerdo

Comment: Pessoal, como faço um auto-incremento a ponto que a cada volta (for) o valor altere para: 000000001,000000002 até chegar 999999999 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 999999999; i++) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%09d", i));
}
```

Veja o exemplo acima funcionando no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/fork/fNTzlo)

Comment: Show, muito obrigado.